# How use Emmet in PHPStorm in PHP files?

Tags: php, phpstorm, emmet

Emmet only works in HTML & CSS files
How can I use it in PHP files in the IDEs like PHPStorm?

```
<?php echo "p>li*5"; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHPStorm, you can just type `echo "p>li*5"` and then make sure your cursor is still inside the quotes and it is at the end of your Emmet string. Hit `Alt + Enter`, then select `Inject Language / Reference`. You will get a list of languages and you can filter by typing. Select `html` and tab completion will work just as in an HTML file.

Comment: Nice try, but i think there must be a simple way for this, the Alt + Enter, then go to inject, then go to HTML is not a good way for fast coding, thanks anyway

Comment: This is the answer for your question. You did not mention anything about speed or efficiency. If you wanna work with `Emmet` and generate larger chunks of code then just close your php tag and it will work just like in an HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are wondering how to get the Emmet to work in .php files but outside the  tags (to generate HTML), just press `Tab` after the Emmet command. Like:

```php-template
<?php if($variable === true): ?>
    span.sometext*3 (press ->Tab)
<?php endif; ?>
```

It generates the following code:

```php-template
<?php if($variable === true): ?>
    <span class="sometext"></span>
    <span class="sometext"></span>
    <span class="sometext"></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's important to tell this because PHPStorm does not show it anywhere, no inline tips, no shortcut tip, neither in that "tips lamp".